# Convert Spark SQL DataFrames to Structured Streaming DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'd like to convert Java Spark SQL DataFrames to Structured Streaming DataFrames, in such a way that every batch would be unioned to the Structured Streaming DataFrame. Therefore I could use the Spark Structured Streaming functionalities (such as a continuous job) on DataFrames that I've got from a batch source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with Java and title a little off-beam.

Unsupported standard operation as you state.

Look in the docs at the the `foreachBatch` implementation. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch  and do the UNION there are having reading the static DF in.